# Do Buddhists believe in Evolution?

Tags: belief, science, evolution

Just as a [companion question to this](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/2220/does-human-evolution-disprove-a-kamma-based-rebirth) I want to ask if Buddhists believe in the theory of evolution by natural selection. The aforementioned question makes me think that the answers might be different depending on which tradition you are coming from. I'm interested in canonical scriptures and more modern commentaries and reinterpretation of the texts.